# JS/CSS Plugin for complex atoms-like dots behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

i'm searching for a technique to display several circles on a website, which has the following requirements:

- circles extend to a rectangle when clicked and show text caption
- circles should move like a vibrating atom, e.g. up/down
- when clicked to open, all open circles should be connected with lines, forming a network
- the circles should not overlay each other, either opened or closed

I already made some effort with it: the circles vibrating effect comes from css3 animations, the connecting lines via javascript on an underlaying html 5 canvas.
Overlay checking for the closed dots happens via position checking in js.

But I've a feeling that there could be a much better solution, moving the dots away from opened dots and so on.

Maybe anyone had done this already?

Greets

Comment: show us what you have done or tried so far

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We are happy to help you with specific programming questions, but overly-broad "Is there another way to do this?" types of questions are [not suitable for this site](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Please consider asking your question again in a way that can be narrowly answered.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at D3js? it's a very nice library for data visualization in JS. I haven't seen your particular example made using D3 but it should be possible :)